# 512 MB RAM enough for Lubuntu with Ubuntu apps?

Tags: lubuntu

I've got a pc that I'd like to install Lubuntu on. I use Ubuntu on my main pc and I'm used to the apps that it ships with - office and mail client is what I use most. So will Lubuntu really be faster on my system if I use LibreOffice and Thunderbird instead of the lighter weight apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is definitely yes.

Ubuntu uses around 300MB ram after booting with no applications running,
whereas Lubuntu uses around 90-100MB ram after booting with no applications running, giving you an extra 200MB ram to play with before you do anything.

Comment: That's cool 'cause legacy RAM is not cheap :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

The environment lxde is lighter so that will speed things up but if you try to use bulky applications you will be disappointed because they will likely come with a lot of dependencies that are common to unity/gnome/kde depending on the particular app you are using.